# Converting string like "2021-05-06 00:00:00 +0530 IST" to time.Time value

Tags: datetime, go, time

I have the following string `2021-05-06 00:00:00 +0530 IST` that I need to convert to a time.Time value in golang. I know how to do it but I don't know what the layout should be to parse these type of strings.

`time, err := time.ParseInLocation("2021-05-06 00:00:00 +0530 IST", addedOn, loc)`

And this is giving me errors like `"error":"parsing time \"2021-05-06 00:00:00 +0530 IST\" as \"2021-05-06 00:00:00 +0530 IST\": cannot parse \"-05-06 00:00:00 +0530 IST\" as \"1\""`

So, what should be the correct layout for such strings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are putting the date in place of the time layout.

See [`time#ParseInLocation`](https://pkg.go.dev/time#ParseInLocation)

```
func ParseInLocation(layout, value string, loc *Location) (Time, error)
```

For instance:

```
loc, _ := time.LoadLocation("Europe/Berlin")

// This will look for the name CEST in the Europe/Berlin time zone.
const longForm = "Jan 2, 2006 at 3:04pm (MST)"
t, _ := time.ParseInLocation(longForm, "Jul 9, 2012 at 5:02am (CEST)", loc)
fmt.Println(t)
```

In your case:

```
t , _ := time.ParseInLocation("2006-01-02 15:04:05 -0700 MST", "2021-05-06 00:00:00 +0530 IST", loc)
```

See [playground example](https://play.golang.org/p/PDvlhEBOloq) (and other [`ParseInLocation` examples here](https://golang.hotexamples.com/examples/time/-/ParseInLocation/golang-parseinlocation-function-examples.html))

Answer (score 1):

**Layout**

```
"2006-01-02 15:04:05 -0700 MST"
```

Look at [docs](https://pkg.go.dev/time#pkg-constants) and [examples](https://golang.org/src/time/example_test.go)

<kbd>[PLAYGROUND](https://play.golang.org/p/p0UVxLa4xHH)</kbd>

Comment: In your playground example, what effect has `time.UTC` as location?

Comment: `ParseInLocation is like Parse but differs in two important ways. First, in the absence of time zone information, Parse interprets a time as UTC; ParseInLocation interprets the time as in the given location. Second, when given a zone offset or abbreviation, Parse tries to match it against the Local location; ParseInLocation uses the given location.` because we use `MST` (`start`), `time .UTC` was ignored.

Comment: "*because we use MST (start), time.UTC was ignored.*" ok thanks, I just found that kind of un-intuitive, I expected something like a conversion to UTC but that might be me being biased by other languages ;-)